# play.libs.WS not recognized in Play framework

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1, playframework-2.2

I am using play.libs.WS in my application, but whenever I compile I get error that play.libs.WS is not resolved. Can someone please help me out in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the issue. I had to include play_2.10.jar and play-datacommons_2.10.jar in my classpath. Thanks everyone for devoting your time.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to add jars manually one by one.

From [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaWS):

> To use WS, first add javaWs to your build.sbt file:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaWs
)
```

And that's all.

Comment: This should be the correct answer.
Use this for Scala:
`libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ws
)`

Answer (score 0):

try the following imports in your controller

import play.api.libs.ws.WS
and
import play.api.libs.ws._